# How to boot live from a DVD when my Macbook's optical drive doesn't work?

Tags: boot, dvd, macbook, drive

I've successfully burned a Ubuntu boot DVD from OS X (Snow Leopard) on my Macbook Pro.  The problem is, the built in optical drive kicked the bucket a few years ago and I've been using an external optical drive that connects via USB.  When I try to boot Ubuntu from the DVD in this drive, it looks like my computer doesn't even recognize the drive during start up.  I hold alt while the computer turns on and it only gives me the option to boot OS X from the hard drive.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry ! You can install Ubuntu using another way, I think USB Bootable is good method, You can create Ubuntu Bootable USB Pen,plug you pen drive and open Startup Disk Creator, make your bootable pen drive

[image]

Comment: I've tried this already with no luck.  I don't want to install Ubuntu yet, I just want to run it from a Live DVD to see what it's like.